# Why does this program give segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pointers, string, segmentation-fault

It's a beginners question: Why is this breaking/giving an error?

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

char *strtrim_right(char *p)
{
  char *end;
  int len;
  len = strlen( p);
  while (*p && len)
    {
    end = p + len-1;
    if(isalpha(*end))
     *end =0;
   else 
    break;      
    }
  return(p);
}


int main ()  
{  
  char *x="PM123BFD";
  strtrim_right(x);
  printf("%s", x);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error? What line? What compiler? What platform? How do you expect we help you if you don't provide information?

Comment: "deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’" for x; rather use a char array: char x[] = ...

Comment: The standard answer: because you invoked undefined behavior. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change

```
char *x="PM123BFD";
```

to

```
char x[]="PM123BFD";
```

You cannot modify a string literal, so instead pass the function a `char` array which it can modify.

Answer (score 5):

I don’t see why it should break – I would rather expect an infinite loop: the `while` condition will always be true and the loop will never be left.

Rework the loop condition, it’s borked. Then look at the variables you have: you never change the values of either `p` or `len`. This isn’t right. Furthermore, the code inside the loop is much more complicated than need be. Think about whether you really need three variables here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to the 2 answers above here is what seems to be ok now:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

char *strtrim_right(char *p)
{
  char *end;
  int len;
  len = strlen( p);
  while (*p && len)
    {
    end = p + len-1;
    if(isalpha(*end))
     *end =0;
   else 
    break;
len = strlen(p);
    }
  return(p);
}


int main ()  
{  
  char x[]="PM123BFD";
  strtrim_right(x);
  printf("%s", x);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why is strtrim_right  returning a char pointer if you aren't using it?

Comment: there’s still a lot wrong with this code. The `while` condition and the code inside the loop are still hopelessly complicated.

Comment: void strtrim_right(char *p)
    {
      p += strlen(p) - 1;
      while(isalpha(*p))
      {
        *p-- = 0;
      }
    }