# bus error 10 in a c program

Tags: c, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between char s[] and char *s in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)
>   [Why does this program give segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735092/why-does-this-program-give-segmentation-fault)

here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char *c){
    int len = strlen(c);
    char tmp;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
        tmp = c[len-1-i];
        c[len-1-i] = c[i];
        c[i] = tmp;
    }
}

int main(){
    char *s = "antonio";
    //printf("%zd\n", strlen(s));
    reverse(s);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

The issue is in reverse(char *c), it take a string ad reverse it, but I don't understand where it goes wrong.

Comment: You're trying to modify a string literal. That's undefined behaviour and usually crashes.

Comment: You've failed to use your compiler warnings and/or pay attention to them. Compile the code again with all warnings enabled and make sure you understand everything the compiler tells you. Automated tools can get you a very long way before you need to come to SO for help!

Comment: @KerrekSB I didn't receive any warning, I will see how to enable all the warnings of my compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two bugs here:

1)

You are trying to change a string literal, which leads to undefined behavior, manifested as bus error in your case.

Change

```
char *s = "antonio";
```

to

```
char s[] = "antonio";
```

2)

Also you are running your loop counter for entire string length:

```
for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
```

this way you'll get back the original string. What you want is to swap only half of the characters with other half:

```
for(i = 0; i < len/2; i++)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/3735133/635608

Comment: @codaddict what is the difference between: char *s = "antonio"; char s[] = "antonio"; char s* = malloc(size);? I know that function(char a[]) became function(char *a), what happen in this case?